# QueryFailedError: Field 'username' doesn't have a default value

Tags: nestjs

Hi I have encountered an error when trying to create new POST request and I believe it has something to do with MYSQL, but I can't figure it out at all. The tables have been created at MYSQL though I can't push any values. ANy help would be appreciated please. Thank You.

Below is my UserService

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from 'src/typeorm/entities/User';
import { CreateUserParams } from 'src/utils/types';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private userRepository: Repository<User>, 
  ) {}
  findUsers() {}

  createUser(userDetails: CreateUserParams) {
    const newUser = this.userRepository.create({
      ...userDetails,
      createdAt: new Date(),
    }); 
    return this.userRepository.save(newUser);
  }
}
```

ALso Below is my entity

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'bigint' })
  id: number;
  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column()
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  authStrategy: string;
}
```

Also below is the screenshot of error

[image]

Comment: You are not passing a username parameter, but the column is defined as non null and does not have a default value. Fix your js code to pass a username value.

Comment: Had the same issue and a little tweek from my postman saved the day... 
Make sure your post header type is set to JSON and not TEXT. 
Find screenshot below https://prnt.sc/r_P4KiS2LOAU

Answer (score 1):

I think you check the following pints to pinpoint the origin of this bug :

1. Check out if the CreateUserParams dto contains the username
2. Check out if the payload of the request contains the username attribute
3. Check out your migration config and files to see if the migrations are functional
   (if you're using synchronize:false)
4. Check out your DB and tables from another viewer(VS Code offers a MySQL viewer, tablePlus .....) to see if you have created a DB and migrations were successful

i think by checking these points you'd be able to find the error reason , good lucks